# :unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

face this typeerror msg when I ran the following code:

```
df_set= pd.read_excel("DATA_SVM.xlsx")

print(df_set.columns)

df1= df_set.drop([0])

df= df1.rename(columns={
    'MSCI World ':'Date',
    'MSCI WORLD U$ - PRICE/BOOK RATIO':'P/B',
    'MSCI WORLD U$ - DIVIDEND YIELD':'YDid',
    'NDDUWI':'Price'})

df['Return']=(df['Price'].shift(-1) - df['Price'])/df['Price']
```

I am sure it is about the last line. What I want to do is to creat a new column 'return' by using the fomular (price2-price1)/price1.

btw, it can be run by Notebook, but response error in Pycharm.

Anyone providing clues would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message provides the clue you need. What do you think a `TypeError` is? What do you think an `operand` is? What do you suppose is supposed to happen when you attempt to subtract a string from a string? Were you *expecting* the code to involve trying to subtract strings from each other? No? Well... where is it subtracting things from each other? Those values must be strings, if it's making such a complaint, yes? So, why are those values strings, and what do you plan to do about it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Price column is formatted as strings. You first need to convert to a type for which subtraction is defined (e.g. float)

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following line can work if I input .xlsx instead of csv.

> df['Return']=(df['Price'].shift(-1) - df['Price'])/df['Price']

but still try to find out how to make it on a csv. file. I am not sure if `.shift` function can be used on csv file.

Maybe it's better to change the topic.
Is there an alternative function that can achieve: elements of the next row in the same column minus elements of the previous row ?